# Hololens2 iris recognition

Tags: hololens, windows-hello

I'm looking for the iris recognition solution and hitting this topic by chance. May I know what Windows APIs we can use for the HL2 iris recognition and where I can find them?  I've looked into the HL2 documentation but unluckily no relevant stuff found.
Thanks so much in advance.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/microsoft-passport

Answer (score 2):

The HoloLens app are UWP app, the iris recognition as biometrics, it belongs to [authentication and user identity area](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/authentication-and-user-identity). You can perform a verification with iris biometrics as in any UWP apps.

First, you need to use [UserConsentVerifier.CheckAvailabilityAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.credentials.ui.userconsentverifier.checkavailabilityasync?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Security_Credentials_UI_UserConsentVerifier_CheckAvailabilityAsync) method to check whether a verifier device is available. Once the biometric device is available, call [UserConsentVerifier.RequestVerificationAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.credentials.ui.userconsentverifier.requestverificationasync?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Security_Credentials_UI_UserConsentVerifier_RequestVerificationAsync_System_String_) method to performs a verification using the biometric device.

Besides, the [UserConsentVerifier sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/UserConsentVerifier) show how to use the UserConsentVerifier class to check whether a verifier device is available and performs the verification, it’s worth reading for you.

Comment: Thank you.According to your prompt. When I called this interface, I found that it uses PIN instead of Iris by default. Excuse me, can I change the default recognition method to Iris?

Comment: @zhoule "it uses PIN instead of Iris by default."  Does it mean that you can manually switch the Windows Hello to iris recognition when login in for your app, but it defaults to using PIN first?

Comment: Yes, when I tested on HoloLens2 according to the instructions of[ this link]:(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/microsoft-passport-login#exercise-1-login-with-microsoft-passport), I found that Iris recognition can be manually selected, but the default recognition is PIN. Can you give me a way to modify this default method?<img src="https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T7N7W6TC0-F016NPN15GC/image.png" width="800" height="600">

Comment: @zhoule Actually, the default verification method is determined by the way the user logs into the device. For example, if the user logs into the device with a PIN instead, the default will be PIN.
Besides, there is not a policy to disable PIN and not a way to make one show up first always, and there is not a way though to change the default option via an API call.